# PDO query syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

could you tell me what is wrong with this query? I have been looking for almost an hour but i could not see any syntax mistake..

```
$query = $database->connection->prepare(
        "SELECT 
        n.from_id AS friend_id, 
        n.type AS type,
        n.created_date AS time,
        u.user_profile_picture AS profile_picture, 
        u.user_firstname AS friend_firstname, 
        u.user_lastname AS friend_lastname, 
        FROM notifications n INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = n.from_id 
        WHERE n.to_id = :user_id AND n.checked = 1");   

    $query->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $query->execute();
```

And this is error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>
> 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
>   notifications n INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = n.from_id WHERE
>   n.to_id =' at line 8' in

Comment: remove the comma before FROM in the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `,` before `FROM`

```
SELECT 
        n.from_id AS friend_id, 
        n.type AS type,
        n.created_date AS time,
        u.user_profile_picture AS profile_picture, 
        u.user_firstname AS friend_firstname, 
        u.user_lastname AS friend_lastname 
        FROM notifications n INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = n.from_id 
        WHERE n.to_id = :user_id AND n.checked = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the comma at the end of line:

```
u.user_lastname AS friend_lastname,
```